# Assembler conditional set not executed

Tags: assembly, x86-64

```
movq $0, %r11
movq $5, %r10
cmpq %r11, %r10
setl %r11b
```

After this, r11 is not set. But from what I understand, 0 is less than 5 so it should be.

I am using gnu assembler and gcc.

```
as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, It seems that you're confused between Intel and AT&T

`cmpq %r11, %r10` in AT&T is equal to `cmp r10, r11` in Intel.

Try `cmpq %r10, %r11` to get your expected result.

Comment: Thanks that was simple, sorry for the noise.

Comment: @user2291758 That kind of bug is one of the buggiest bug in the world >o<